# cant change font color to white in css navbar

Tags: css, wordpress

i am trying to make the color of my .blou class with a white color this is my nav i gave them a class in my wordpress but the colorseems to not change
this is from the wordpress theme

```
 .nav-menu ul li a {
    color: #222;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.nav-menu ul li a:hover {
   background-color: #000F3A;
    color:white;
 
}
```

then i added this `

```
.nav-menu ul li.blou1 {
   background-color: #000F3A;
    color:white!important;
 
}`
```

for some reason the background does change but not the text color to white please help someone

My Menu Contains

Home|Gallery|Contact|About|Members|Login(.blou1 class)|Register(.blou1 class)

also when i hover over the class blou1 it should remove the background and change the text to black or something

Comment: Can you post the HTML for your navigation links? If you have added `.blou1` to the `<li>` as you have suggested, then try this selector: `.nav-menu ul li.blou1 a:hover` (you need to target the color of `<a>` not of `<li>` to affect the hover state styling).

Comment: Oh and you shouldn't need `!important` if you use the correct selector as selecting an element by class is considered more specific than selecting by just element type. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#selector_types

Comment: i went to the appearance menus| and under my menu item i added the class i want to the class tab

Comment: You may need to learn how to use your browser's developer tools to understand the structure of your HTML. It will depend on your wordpress theme as to which element the `.blou1` class is applied and the relation of that element to the one you actually want to style. Here's a link to a beginner's article to help you see which element has the `blou1` class, if you are using Google Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css If you're using a different browser, search for "developer tools css {your browser}"

Comment: Thank You i fixed it with
 .nav-menu ul li#menu-item-192 a{
  background-color: #000F3A;
    color:white;
}

Answer (score 0):

try adding this code snippet instead the snippet you have added, it should work:

```css
.blou1 {
    background-color: #000F3A;
    color:white!important;
}

.blou1:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: have you added the class names to your html tag? it would be good if you could paste some code.

Comment: no i use the drop down option in wordpress that say Class for your menu items